# How to put color highligts on forms with Javascript without inline styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, inline

I made an HTML form that consists of an alert message with javascript. I need to change this alert message into a red/green color highlight box with Javascript without using inline CSS.

This is how it looks now:

```
function validateFormC() {
let x = document.forms["contactForm"]["name_contact"].value;
if (x === "") {
    alert("Don't forget to fill in your name!");
    return false;
}
x = document.forms["contactForm"]["email_contact"].value;
if (x === "") {
    alert("Don't forget to fill in your e-mail!");
    return false;
}
}
```

So what I need is to get a red/green box instead of an alert message. And also to convert the alert message next to the textbox would be nice. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your attempt - what works and what doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

No. alert() accepts a string and renders it using a native widget. There is no provision to style it.

Comment: You understood the question wrong - the OP is asking how to style a textbox that is the replacement for the alert.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You cant change alert msg color but you can use different plugin which works same as alert and also gives beautiful design of alert.And it is very easy to use.Please check this.[sweet alert](https://sweetalert.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create (overwrite) alert() and then you could update the template style.

**But this is not proper way!**

```js
alert('Your alert message.');
```

```html
<script>
window.alert = function(text = '') {
    const d = document;
    const alertId = 'custom-alert';
    const hostname = window.location.hostname;

    const style = `<style id="${alertId}-style">
                #${alertId} {
                    --padding:16px;

                    position:fixed;
                    top:0;
                    left:50%;
                    transform:translateX(-50%);
                    width:450px;
                    min-height:132px;
                    padding:var(--padding);
                    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
                    box-shadow:0 0 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
                    border-radius:5px;
                    font-size:12px;
                    color:#000
                }

                #${alertId} span {
                    display:block
                }

                #${alertId} span:first-of-type {
                    font-size:var(--padding);
                    padding-bottom:var(--padding)
                }

                #${alertId} span:first-of-type::after {
                    content:attr(data-host)
                }

                #${alertId} span:last-of-type {
                    color:#666
                }

                #${alertId} div {
                    position:absolute;
                    bottom:var(--padding);
                    right:var(--padding);
                    min-width:60px;
                    background:#3F86F4;
                    color:#fff;
                    text-align:center;
                    padding:10px
                }
                #${alertId} div::before {
                    content:attr(data-ok)
                }

                #${alertId} div:active {
                    background:#6ba0f4
                }
            </style>`;

    const template = `<div id="${alertId}">
                        <span data-host="${hostname.length ? hostname : 'localhost'} says"></span>
                        <span>${text}</span>
                        <div data-ok="OK"></div>
                    </div>`;

    d.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', style + template);

    const alertModal = d.querySelector('#' + alertId);

    alertModal.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', () => {
        const alertStyle = d.querySelector(`#${alertId}-style`);
        alertStyle.parentNode.removeChild(alertStyle);
        alertModal.parentNode.removeChild(alertModal);
    });
};
</script>
```